# How to make listings package break TeX code only after control sequences?

Tags: listings, line-breaking, characters

Package `listings` always likes to break TeX code **after** backslashes. How to make it always break **before** backslashes?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines,language=TeX]
\def\beamer@toc@subsubsectionstyle#1{\beamer@toc@ssprocess\beamer@toc@csss\beamer@toc@osss\beamer@toc@oosss\beamer@toc@ooosss#1////}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: The question should be made clearer as -- *How to make `listings` package break TeX code only **after** control sequences?*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent the breaks after `\` by making this a letter, via `alsoletter={\\}`.  However, arbitrary breaks before `\` are dangerous and can give the wrong syntax from tex TeX point of view.

```
\def\a{\b}
```

is not the same as

```
\def\a{
\b}
```

which is equivalent to

```
\def\a{ \b}
```

On the other hand

```
\def\a{\b\c}
\def\a{\b \c}
\def\a{\b
\c}
```

are equivalent.  I suggest you add spaces where appropriate, for example could be entered:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines,language=TeX,alsoletter={\\}]
  \def\beamer@toc@subsubsectionstyle#1{%
  \beamer@toc@ssprocess \beamer@toc@csss \beamer@toc@osss \beamer@toc@oosss \beamer@toc@ooosss#1////}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In fact I want to `\lstinputlisting` many source files of `beamer` package. Therefore it is not practical for me to add spaces manually. And `alsoletter={\\}` conflicts with `keywordstyle=\color{blue}`. But I don't care about syntax problem because I will add `prebreak` and `postbreak` tokens. Are there any other better solution?

Comment: @Z.H. Line breaks in TeX code should be added manually. This also provides for better coding to begin with.

Comment: @egreg I know how to correctly break TeX code when writing macros. But that is another situation. Maybe I should change the question to "How to make `listings` package break lines only after TeX control sequences?"